# What is tripping up clang but not g++ in compiling a simple Ceres Solver demo?

Tags: c++, linker

I have a short program, quad1.cpp, which uses Ceres Solver, which requires some heavy math libraries, pthread, C++11 features and uses templates like crazy. I compile it fine with

```
g++ -o quad1  -std=c++14  quad1.cpp  -I/usr/include/eigen3    -lceres -lcxsparse -llapack -lblas -lcholmod -lm -lglog  -lgomp -lpthread
```

But if I change 'g++' to 'clang' it won't compile, giving this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/quad1-89905a.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEaSEPKc@@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

The mangled names demangles to some sort of basic_string with traits and allocators, which is gobbledygoop to me.  Do I need to link also to some sort of string library?

I'm running on Arch Linux, fully updated about two months ago. GCC is version 6.1.1, and clang is version 3.8.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gcc` is to `g++` what `clang` is to `clang++` :)

Basically, clang by default doesn't compile with the `stdlibc++` flag, as does gcc. This results in the C libraries being linked, which do not contain `std::basic_string` and similar classes from the C++ library.

So, either specify `-stdlib=libstdc++`, or compile with `clang++`, which links it by default with `libstdc++`.